# Repeat Python function call on exception?

Tags: python

Hey everybody I'm working on a data scraping project and I'm looking for a clean way to repeat a function call if an exception is raised.

Pseudo-code:

```
try:
    myfunc(x)
except myError:
    ###try to call myfunc(x) again Y number of times, 
        until success(no exceptions raised) otherwise raise myError2
```

I realize this isn't best practice at all but I'm working through a number of different code/network layers that aren't reliable and I can't realistically debug them.

Right now I'm accomplishing this with a huge set of try\except blocks and it's making my eyes bleed.

Elegant ideas anyone?

Comment: This is a situation where a goto would be incredibly useful.

Comment: @Rafe: No, it really wouldn't.

Comment: [`from __past__ import goto`](http://entrian.com/goto/)

Comment: Generally, and especially in case of a networking task an [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) should be used to find appropriate rate. Retrying right away may lead to waste of resources. The idea is illustrated in this [Python decorator recipe wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Retry).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do precisely what you want, you could do something like the following:

```
import functools
def try_x_times(x, exceptions_to_catch, exception_to_raise, fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn) #keeps name and docstring of old function
    def new_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in xrange(x):
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except exceptions_to_catch:
                 pass
        raise exception_to_raise
    return new_fn
```

Then you just wrap the old function in this new function:

```
#instead of
#risky_method(1,2,'x')
not_so_risky_method = try_x_times(3, (MyError,), myError2, risky_method)
not_so_risky_method(1,2,'x')

#or just
try_x_times(3, (MyError,), myError2, risky_method)(1,2,'x')
```

Comment: Use functools.wraps instead of changing \_\_name\_\_ yourself.

Comment: Cool. I actually ended up using http://peter-hoffmann.com/2010/retry-decorator-python.html but it's pretty much the same idea.

Answer (score 8):

Use a loop

```
i = 0
while True:
  try: myfunc(x); break;
  except myError:
    i = i + 1;
    # print "Trying again"
    if i > 5: raise myError2;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for x in xrange(num_retries):
    try:
        myFunc()
    except MyError, err:
        continue
        #time.sleep(1)
    err = None
    break
if err:
    raise MyError2
#else:
#    print "Success!"
```

Answer (score 4):

To raise Exception as usual after n retries

```
from functools import wraps

def retry(times):
    """
    Decorator to retry any functions 'times' times.
    """
    def retry_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def retried_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(times - 1):
                try:
                    func(*args, **kwargs)
                    return
                except Exception:  
                    pass
            func(*args, **kwargs)

        return retried_function

    return retry_decorator


# test

attempts = 3

@retry(4)
def function_that_raises_error():
    global attempts
    if 0 < attempts:
        print("fail")
        attempts -= 1
        raise Exception

    print("pass")

function_that_raises_error()
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to do these problems with recursion:

```
def tryfor(times, on_failure, excepts, func, *args, **kwargs):
    if times < 1:
        raise on_failure()
    try:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except excepts:
        return tryfor(times-1, on_failure, excepts, func, *args, **kwargs)


tryfor(3, PermanentException, (SomeError,), dostuff,1,2)
```

Comment: Does it tail-optimize?

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet:

```
while True:
    try:
        func()
        break
    except:
        print "Error. Gonna try again"
```

But it is better to limit the number of retries.

Comment: `except:` is not a good idea in most (*but not all*) cases. I'd rather use `except Exception:`. And this of course assumes that `func()` will terminate at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
success = False
attempts = 0
while not success and attempts < 10: # or however many times you want to attempt
    try:
        functionCall()
        success = True
    except:
        i += 1
if not success:
    raise functionCallFailedError
```

Hope this helps