# Python Adding a retry after exceptions is raised

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

i've inherited a code that needs a bit of a rework. A spectrum scan error keeps happening and this is the place where the exception is raised:

```
try:
    # iterate trough each record in json file
    for i in sorted(tables_to_load, key=lambda x: (tables_to_load[x]["order"])):
        # print(i)
        # if table exclude flag is set to "N", proceed with load_table()
        if tables_to_load[i]["exclude"] == "N":
            try:
                job_start_time = datetime.now()
                logger.info("Begin load for: %s ---- %s ----" %(tables_to_load[i]["order"], i))
                error_code = load_table(i, tables_to_load[i], from_date, to_date, max_proc, dm_updated, 
                process_flag)
                job_end_time = datetime.now()
                job_duration = (job_end_time - job_start_time).total_seconds()
                logger.info("Load for table: %s -- time: %s seconds." %(i, job_duration))
            except Exception as e:
                #this is where the error is cought
                logger.error("Load for table: %s FAILED: %s" %(i, e))
                raise
        #else the table is excluded and we skip it
        else:
            logger.info("Table excluded from load: %s " %i)
except Exception as e:
    # upload error log to s3
    s3.upload_file(filepath + filename, s3_logbucket, s3_logprefix + filename)
    raise
```

Basically, the script reads a json cfg file containing a list of  externatl tables partitioned by YYYYMMDD or YYYYMMDDhhmmss) , RS tables and RS store procedures which load the data from S3 to RS.
When the error is caught, I don't want the error to be raised. Or rather, I want to give it 3 times before the error is raised. I need help writing that iteration?

Thanks,
Rosa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat Python function call on exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766556/repeat-python-function-call-on-exception)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the retry policy set for 3 times (**Retry attempts** under **Asynchronous invocation** section), it will automatically retry when you raise an exception. If you're using SQS or Kinesis to trigger the lambda function, it ensures that the lambda is retried.

If you don't need to go on that route, you can simply modify your code to retry.

```
retries = 0
retry_limit = 3

while retries < retry_limit:
    try:
        # you code goes here
        break
    except Exception as e:
        # log the error
        retries += 1
        if retries == retry_limit:
            raise e
```

However, I don't recommend this. The reason is, lambda has a limited lifespan, and retrying manually will consume that.

So, try to incoperate the first option.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. the code runs through SQL Server job. It's not a Lambda. I'm gonna try this and let you know the results.

Comment: Ahh okay, I didn't realize it's a generic question. Then don't forget to add `break`.